# Why this modal form is getting redirected to my php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have been trying to work with this form that I took from other website of mine, but it's not working in a new website I am creating.
What am I missing here? Maybe the form should be used different when is into a modal?
I just don't want to be redirected when submitting the form to the .php file. Any suggest?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Fincas Morales</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Custom styles for  -->
  <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- JQUERY CDN -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">

  <!-- Modal Header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Ingrese sus Datos:</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
     <form id="cform" action="mailer1.php" method="post">
       <div class="form-row">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" name="name">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" name="phone">
         </div>

       </div>
       <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Correo" name="email" required>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dim" placeholder="Dirección de inmueble" name="dim">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="diudad" placeholder="Ciudad" name="ciudad">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="poblacion" placeholder="Población" name="poblacion">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="viviendas" placeholder="N° Viviendas" name="viviendas">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="garajes" placeholder="N° Garajes" name="garajes">
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trasteros" placeholder="N° Trasteros" name="trasteros">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locales" placeholder="Locales" name="locales">
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ascensores" placeholder="Ascensores" name="ascensores">
         </div>
         <span class="mr-1">Portería:</span>
         <div class="col-1 custom-control custom-radio">

           <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="r1" name="por" value="Si">
           <label class="custom-control-label" for="r1">Sí</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-1 custom-control custom-radio">
           <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="r2" name="por" value="No">
           <label class="custom-control-label" for="r2">No</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="ozc" placeholder="Otras zonas comunes" name="ozc" rows="3"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="mensaje" placeholder="Su Mensaje:" name="mensaje" rows="3"></textarea>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div id="form-messages" class="mt-2 p-2 text-center success error" style="display:none;"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
  </div>
     </form>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app1.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the .app1 file with the jQuery AJAX code:

```
$(function() {
// Get the form.
var form = $('#cform');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(event) {
// Stop the browser from submitting the form.
event.preventDefault();

// Serialize the form data.
var formData = $(form).serialize();

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');

    // Set the message text.
    $(formMessages).text(response);

    // Clear the form.
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#message').val('');
})

.fail(function(data) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    // Set the message text.
    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and
your message could not be sent.');
    }
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
$("#cform").submit(....)
```

and for form data variable you can try
also

```
var formdata=new FormData(this);
```

another thing is to look your console to see if some bug appear

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The problem was a simple unintended line break on "$(formMessages).text(...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, any button or Js function to open the model by default. 
So if you are getting the form view by running the index.html. It means your bootstrap.min.css is not loaded.

check your path to bootstrap.min.css
add the line to open the model on click

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Everything looks fine till here. try and let me know. Please check the console while submitting.

Comment: Hi, Saurav. The problem was a line break in the jQuery AJAX code. Somehow, that simple line break in the "$(formMessages).text(...) was causing troubles. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: yup, I got that too in my editor. But anyway I ignored that.